# How to connect Crystal Report to MS Access database using C# in Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, crystal-reports

I want to connect Crystal Reports to MS Access database using C# in my windows form application.

I am using below code to connect crystal report with MS Access database but it is not working.

```
ReportDocument crReport = new ReportDocument(); 
string sTemplatePath = "D:\\Report\\Sample.rpt";

crReport.Load(sTemplatePath);

TableLogOnInfo crTableLogOnInfo = new TableLogOnInfo(); 
ConnectionInfo tConnInfo = new ConnectionInfo(); 
tConnInfo.DatabaseName = "D:\\AccessDB\\AccessDb.mdb"; 
tConnInfo.Password = "abcd"; 
foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table crTable in crReport.Database.Tables) 
{             
    crTableLogOnInfo = crTable.LogOnInfo;
    crTableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = tConnInfo;
    crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crTableLogOnInfo); 
}
```

Can anyone help me to achieve this task? I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: It looks OK to me.  Technically you should not need the database name.  How have you secured the database?  Just using password?  Or with a mdw file?  Normally when you are designing the .rpt file using access you will have had to enter password details there.  Did this work ok?  On what line is the above failing?  I will need a bit more info to help you more.

Comment: _Thanks Jonathan Willcock for you reply,_
Actually, I am working on a small application with MS Access database which I have secured it with password only. The problem is when I debug my code, it does not entered in the foreach loop and crReport.Database.Tables object return this below in my immediate window.

'crReport.Database.Tables
{CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Tables}
    Count: 0
    Current: 'crReport.Database.Tables.Current' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentException'

Comment: Then it sounds like your report file is wrong, rather than your c# code.  When you were designing the report, did you successfully preview your required data?

Comment: I have only created parameter for my report and drop it on the report file. I want to bind crystal report with data using code.

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot do it that way.  You have to create a report file for which you will be prompted for connection and tables etc. and in which you can do your layout.  At runtime you can then provide connection info to a different database as long as the new database has the same tables.

Answer (score 0):

Steps you need to take:

1. Create your .rpt file.  For this I always use a separate library in which I keep all my reports, but this is not necessary, you can do it in your main solution.  Either way, you must make sure you have references to CrustalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine; CrustalDecisions.ReportSource; CrustalDecisions.Shared; and CrustalDecisions.Windows.Forms.
2. You can now right-click your project, Add, New Item, and then under Visual c# you will see Crystal Reports.  Choose your report name, click Add, Accept the default of Using the Report Wizard and Standard layout.  Now expand Create New Connection, click Access/Excel and you will be prompted for the location of your database file.  Since you have password protected it, you must now click Secure Logon and enter the password (as Database password).  When you click Finish, you should now see your database file and under it a list of tables etc.  Select the one(s) that are the basis for your report, use the arrow to move it/them to Selected tables (right hand side).  Click Next and then select the Fields that you need in the same way.  You may now click Finish.
3. Add A CrystalReportViewer control to a Form which is to be the "host" form for the report.
4. Use the same c# code as you have in the constructor of your host form to connect to the database.  This may be a different database with a different password, as long as it has the same table(s).
5. Finally add the following code:

   ```
   //Assign data source details to the report viewer
   if (this.crystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo != null)
   {
       TableLogOnInfos tlInfo = this.crystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo;
       foreach (TableLogOnInfo tbloginfo in tlInfo)
       {
           tbloginfo.ConnectionInfo = tConnInfo;
       }
   }
   crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crReport;
   ```

Once you have got the basics working, you can start playing around with the design of your report, using the WYSIWYG designer!